# Apache Netbeans 11.3 not running unless I use terminal and set jdkhome

Tags: jdk, netbeans

I had Apache NetBeans 11.1 with JDK 11 running fine.

Then NetBeans upgraded to 11.3, and for some reason it didn't see JDK, so I downloaded JDK 14 and added it to NetBeans Platforms. All working fine.

Ubuntu upgraded to 19.10.

Apache Netbeans now is not working from Favorites icon, no matter how many times I click.

I removed NB for Ubuntu Software, then reinstalled it from terminal, but it stopped for some error fetching jdk from archive, so I installed it from snap.

I have to open terminal and run

```
netbeans --jdkhome /home/username/myjavafolder/jdk-14.0.1
```

It works fine, and in `Tools\Java Platforms` is shows JDK 14 is the default platform. But I don't want to open terminal each time I run NetBeans.

In Ubuntu Software it shows Apache NetBeans is installed, but when I right-click on the favorite icon and click "Show Details", Ubuntu Software shows "Unable to find netbeans_netbeans.desktop"

I changed the `netbeans.conf` to point to the above jdkhome.

I also changed `JAVA_HOME` variable as well (using `JAVA_HOME=$"/home/username/myjavafolder/jdk-14.0.1"`, but after reboot, it got reset for some reason (when I `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get an empty line)

using `which` in terminal shows netbeans is at `snap/bin/netbeans`, but in this file properties it show its link target is `/usr/bin/snap`. Is this related somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that I think are not necessarily connected in your question.

### 1. Java

You have set your JDK in an unusual folder and I bet that Ubuntu is half or not aware of it. What do you get if you enter the commands `which java` and `which javac` ?

Normally, you can update your default JDK with the command `sudo update-alternative --config java` (and then the same with javac). The terminal will then display all the JVM / JDK it founds, with a star in front of the currently used one. You can enter the number of the one you wish to use in place of the current one.

This might already solve your problem. If it does, then perfect, don't check further, that's the only thing that was missing.

On a side note, if you want to permanently set the JAVA_HOME variable, you will have to edit the ~/.bashrc file, and add at the end of this file:
`export JAVA_HOME=/home/username/myjavafolder/jdk-14.0.1`
But I am not sure that this is causing your problem so this is more for information...

Please note that if you wish to use JDK 14 for NetBeans only and another JDK for your system, then you should keep the update-alternatives command pointing on the desired system JDK and specify your NetBeans JDK in netbeans.conf (as you seems having done actually).

### 2. NetBeans Launcher

From what you say, the NetBeans icon does not launch NetBeans anymore. Maybe you could use your graphical menu editor to check what commands this icon is actually executing when you click on it ? You should also check what the current command is doing, which NetBeans binary it tries to execute, and check if this binary file indeed exists.

I suspect that there might be some mess due to different consecutive NetBeans locations or installations, with the launcher not correctly updated in between.

You could edit the command, so basically copy / paste the one you successfully use from terminal. If you do this, you should be able to launch again NetBeans from its icon, as you do from terminal. But I would rather recommend you to fix your JDK location as it sounds a "cleaner" way to solve your problem.

### 3. NetBeans itself

Last thing, I wonder where your NetBeans is, or how many NetBeans you have installed in your session. How did you install NetBeans? You mention you edited the netbeans.conf file. Where was it located ? I am asking because it seems that you installed NetBeans via snap, but if this is correct then you should not have been able to edit the .conf file.

If you cannot get a working NetBeans from any of the above steps, I would suggest uninstalling the snap package. The icon should have disappeared. You should not get any result for `which netbeans` in terminal.

If you have found another NetBeans install at step 2, you should also remove it. If this is fine, any if you have fixed your JDK path, then try to re-install NetBeans.

You should be done now!

I hope you will get NetBeans working with these steps. If you don't please provide the outputs of the `which` and `update-alternatives` commands I mentioned in my answer, and we'll further think to it.

Comment: Thanks! Downloaded java 14 from PPA from [here](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-openjdk-14-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/). All working now.